# Unity constructor with default params

Tags: c#, unity-container, code-injection

Problem with injection of constructor with default params.

For example

```
container.RegisterType<IAddressImportRepository, AddressImportRepository>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

public AddressImportRepository(
    FairFlexxDbContext context, bool isUseSecurePredicate = true)
    : base(context, isUseSecurePredicate)
{
}
```

Error:

> [InvalidOperationException: The type Boolean does not have an
>   accessible constructor.]
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForNullExistingObject(IBuilderContext
>   context) +239    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +60
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +71
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +42
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +333
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +274
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey) +167
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext
>   context) +101    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +425
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +71
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +42
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +333
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +274
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey) +167
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext
>   context) +101    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +222
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +71
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +42
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +333
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +274
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +383

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unity uses reflection to determine the constructor parameter types.  With your constructor, it found parameters FairFlexxDbContext and bool.  It tries to construct an instance of each type and fails on the bool because it is a value type.  It does not recognize the default value you have supplied to get past this error.

To get this to work, you have a couple options.  Either tell the register your `IAddressImportRepository` with an [`InjectionConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.injectionconstructor(v=pandp.30).aspx) and tell it *how* to resolve your constructor parameters or move your bool parameter to be a property instead.  Since the bool is an optional parameter, I would recommend moving it to be a property.

```
container.RegisterType<IAddressImportRepository, AddressImportRepository>(
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<FairFlexxDbContext>(), true));
```

or

```
public AddressImportRepository(FairFlexxDbContext context)
    : base(context, true)
{
    IsUseSecurePredicate = true;
}

public bool IsUseSecurePredicate { get; set; }
```